# Backup Google Shared Drive files and folders

Tags: google-drive-api, backup

In our company, we use Google Enterprise, and Shared Drives to store all our documents. After chatting with Google support agents, it seems there is no way to backup some of our folders and files.

We have two different needs:
- keeping a regularly syynchronized backup of some sensible files updated regularly
- backing up every month some files as they are on the backup date, and creating a specific copy for each monthly backup

Anyone has a way to do either of those things?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "Google assisstants"? Did you talk with google support agents? 
Could you provide more information in the steps you took to contact google support?
And where is that you would like to store your backup? In a local storage>

Comment: yes, sorry, I mean I talked with google support agents (via the admin help center available with Google enterprise accounts) 
I'd consider any option to store the backup, the issue here being more about avoiding the manual process of backing up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a program/script based on the Google Drive API https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk

Or, try a third-party Google Enterprise data backup tool, like CubeBackup or Spanning.